# How to get a test result output file attachment from remote test agent for mstest

Tags: mstest, coded-ui-tests, testcontext

My MSTest creates an artifact the end and attached it to the test output using `TestContext.AddResultFile`.

If I run the test on my local machine then the attached files are available with test output, but when I run the test on a remote test agent the output doesn't have any files attached with it.

I have checked all options in the "Data and Diagnostics" section in `.testsettings` file, but nothing worked.

How can i get the test results attachments from remote test agent?

Answer (score 0):

When you run an automated test via Microsoft Test Manager and add a file using TestContext.AddResultFile the file will be stored on the machine that the Test Controller is installed on, not on the Test Agent machine.

Look in the following location on the Test Controller Machine for the file:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTController\55\Results\e577b60e-8bec-4b04-a175-a90b6cebecc7\test agent machine name\

Username: the user the Test Controller runs with.

55: the test run number from MTM.

e577b60e-8bec-4b04-a175-a90b6cebecc7: this will be unique to your test run.

Test agent machine name: the full Test Agent machine's name.